# How to prevent other apps to read NFC tags when my app is in foreground?

Tags: android, nfc

I want to avoid the dialog that pops up displaying the different apps available to read a NFC Tag when my app is in foreground. Is that even possible?

Comment: did you checkout http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html

Specifically, `Using the Foreground Dispatch System` section

Comment: Thank you. This definitively helps